# Combine 2 overloading method into one

Tags: asp.net, overloading

I have 2 methods with same name, but different number of parameters (Method overloading). I want to merge these two functions into one. Is it possible way?
Here are some code:

```
private void Fill(string ViewStateName, string type1, string type2,
                  string type3, string type4, string type5, string type6,
                  string val1, string val2, string val3, string val4, string val5, string val6, 
                  string VCol1, string VCol2, string VCol3, string VCol4, string VCol5, string VCol6,
                  GridView gv, DataTable table, DataTable tableMore, string Sessiontable, 
                  string SessiontableMore, string SessionRestTable, string SessionEditTbl)
{
    //code
}

private void Fill(string ViewStateName, string type1, string type2, string type3, 
                  string type4, string type5, string type6, string type7, string val1, 
                  string val2, string val3, string val4, string val5, string val6, 
                  string val7, string VCol1, string VCol2, string VCol3, string VCol4, 
                  string VCol5, string VCol6, string VCol7, GridView gv, DataTable table,
                  DataTable tableMore, string Sessiontable, string SessiontableMore, 
                  string SessionRestTable, string SessionEditTbl)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: If your methods do the same thing, you may just delete the first method (with less number of parameters), and in the big one initalize absent parameters with null

Comment: @AwakeningByte gave an example how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define one function with optional parameters

```
private void Fill(string ViewStateName, string type1, string type2, string type3, 
              string type4, string type5, string type6, string type7, string val1, 
              string val2, string val3, string val4, string val5, string val6, 
              string val7, string VCol1, string VCol2, string VCol3, string VCol4, 
              string VCol5, string VCol6, string VCol7, GridView gv, DataTable table,
              DataTable tableMore, string Sessiontable, string SessiontableMore = "", 
              string SessionRestTable = "", string SessionEditTbl = "")
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: What is the different between using "Empty String" and "Null"?

Comment: Null works for me with .net 4.5. I guess you are using an earlier version